which annotation property should I use to add deprecated label for a concept?
There were different labels to indicate a concept in Protege (now deprecated or no longer in use), however the concept still exists and it has a current standardized name, which I mention in the "rdfs:label" annotation property. I am aware of owl:deprecated, however I would like to add a deprecated label to the concept, and not mark the concept deprecated.

It is possible to annotate OWL axioms: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Annotating_Axioms_and_Entities. See also https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#xl
